# dimple.js filter x axis with date range

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I am working on dimple js (d3) charts and looking for filtering it with date range.
Shortly i am developing graph with date range inputs and after submit that form my dimple.js chart will be refreshed and shows chart for selected date range.

I am using .tsv file for genrating report graph. my code look like below.

```
d3.tsv("data.tsv", function (data) {
    myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
    myChart.setMargins("60px", "10px", "10px", "75px");
    var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Month");
    x.addOrderRule("Date");
    var y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Sales Value");
    y.showGridlines = true;
    y.tickFormat = ',.2f';    
    myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
    myChart.draw(1000);
});
```

Help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue. Did you ever find a solution to this other than redrawing the chart as Parth suggests?

Answer (score 0):

> I am afraid you cannot do that directly in dimple.js.

A much better and easier way is to create and filter your dataset each time you submit your form and render the dimple chart again. I had worked on a similar project a few days back where I had to filter my dimple graph according to a range set by the user.

Instead of taking the .tsv file directly as your data, you can put the contents your file in a 2D array, representing rows and columns of your file. I had done this using java and had then passed this array to my JavaScript code.

Suppose that `xydata[][]` is our array, the "Months" column is stored in the row `xydata[0][i]` and that the "Sales Value" column is stored in the row `xydata[1][i]`

Now, each time you submit the form, you need to create the data set, filtering as required. The code is something as follows:

```
function createChart(range)
{
xydata=[["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May"],[10,20,30,40,50]];  //Created data example

var data=[]; //Array for filtered data

var range="Apr";   //Passed from the form

for(var i=0;i<xydata[0].length;i++){
  if(range<xydata[0][i])  //Filtering Condition.. Additional logic required here
data.push({
  Months:xydata[0][i],
  SalesValue:xydata[1][i]
}
         );
}

//data now contains the filtered data (before April in this case)

myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);

//and then draw the chart accordingly.
};
```

Note: You will require some additional logic to let the compiler know, for example, Jan < Apr

I have written a generic example